# Typescript not inferring correct type after type check inside a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I have this component that takes an `error` prop that might be `null`, `string` or `string[]`.

```
interface ErrorComponent {
  error: null | string | string[]      // props.error UNION TYPES
}

const ErrorComponent: React.FC<ErrorComponent> = (props) => {

  const errorItems = props.error ?               // CHECK IF props.error EXISTS (string | string[])
    Array.isArray(props.error) ?                 // CEHCK IF props.error IS AN ARRAY
      props.error.map((item,index) =>            // CASE string[]
        <Error_DIV 
          key={index} 
          marginBottom={index === props.error.length -1 ? "0px" : "8px"}   // GETTING WARNING FOR POSSIBLE null HERE
        >
          {item}
        </Error_DIV>
      )
    : <Error_DIV>{props.error}</Error_DIV>       // CASE string
  : null;                                        // CASE null

  // return SOMETHING
};
```

[image]

Typescript is complaining that `props.error` could be `null`. But at that point, I've already made the check `Array.isArray(props.error)`. So, there's no way the `props.error` could be `null`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this TSLint rule does not support JSX very well:

```
props.error.map((item,index) => 
    <Error_DIV // Here TSLINT context seems to be reset
```

However, it is recommended to use Elvis operator "?." but in your case it's not possible due to the "-1" operation. So you have to test props.error again:

In your case :

```
marginBottom={props.error && index === props.error.length -1 ? "0px" : "8px"}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I add the `?` as in `props.error?.length`, I'm getting _Object is possibly 'undefined'_.

Comment: right, that's because the "-1". I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when using `map()` on an array with possible different types. You did a check for null and a check for an array so when those checks are passed you can be sure that your error props are an array of strings, you can do something like this:

```
(props.error as string[]).map((item,index)
```

Or you can use the `string[]` directly on the `props.error` in your shorthand if statement

```
marginBottom={index === (props.error as string[]).length -1 ? "0px" : "8px"}
```

Adding an additional null check:

```
marginBottom={props.error && index === props.error.length -1 ? "0px" : "8px"}
```

Using the `! operator` to define this property as not null:

```
marginBottom={index === props.error!.length -1 ? "0px" : "8px"}
```